# How can I format text axis labels with exponents in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data is structured as follows:

```
X <- c("KKKK", "BB", "ABBB", "CCCC")
Y <- c(10, 14, 9, 10)

RawData <- data.frame(X, Y)
```

I can plot this in ggplot using the following:

```
ggplot(RawData, aes(X, Y)) + 
  geom_point()
```

However, instead of using the label KKKK, I wish the plot label to instead read: K^4. Consequently, the other labels would be:
B^2, AB^3, C^4

I know that axis labels can be created in ggplot2 using the following line of code:

```
xlab(bquote('Assimilation ('*mu~ 'mol' ~CO[2]~ m^-2~s^-1*')'))
```

But how do I do this for tick labels?

Thank you.

Comment: `p+  scale_x_discrete(labels=expression(AB^3, B^2, C^4, K^4))`

Comment: Thank you! Embarrassed it was that easy to do...